# Как написать поиск по mysql?

Tags: поиск, mysql

Как написать страничку с поиском по mysql? Поиск должен быть по полям:

- название
- название набора
- артикул
- фабрика (выпадающим списком)

Поиск должен быть независимым, т.е. введя одно поле, не обязательно забивать второе поле, ещё он должен, забив часть слова, находить все варианты, где эта часть встречается. Выводить должен в таблице:

1. название
2. название набора
3. артикул
4. фабрика
5. цена
6. инфа

Все есть в БД, надо написать только поиск. Плюс ещё вход на страницу должен быть после проверки логина.

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Готова часть кода, но уровень написания у меня очень мал:(

Поэтому не могу разобраться, как прикрутить или создать систему логина и пароля... и не знаю, как посылать запрос в разные таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function create_search_query($strict=true,$fields=null){
//-название -название набора -артикул -фабрика
//Если специфический массив не передан, заполняем стандартным
    if(!$fields){
        $fields = array('name','set_name','art_number','factory');
    }
    //массив условий
    $condition = array();
    foreach($fields as $fname){
        //Ищем поля в запросе. Если поля нет, оставляем пустым
        if(!empty($_REQUEST[$fname])){
            $_REQUEST[$fname] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$fname]);
            $condition[]=sprintf("`%s` like '%%%s%%'",$fname,$_REQUEST[$fname]);
        }
    }
    //Если поиск строгий, используем И, если нестрогий - ИЛИ
    $cond_operator = $strict?"AND":"OR";
    if(!empty($condition)){
        $condition = " where ".implode(" ".$cond_operator." ",$condition);
    }
    //Вывод запроса. Остается только загнать его в DBENGINE_query();
    return "select * from `your_table` ".$condition;

}
```

Comment: Что касается авторизации - надо знать что конкретно требуется. Есть готовый класс, поделиться не жалко, но существует куча ресурсов с гораздо более простыми решениями, если не требуется особой секьюрности

Comment: **knes** , Ваш код очень интересный :) Но он у меня работает не полностью :(

У меня в форме есть 1 параметр, за который отвечает одна кнопка radio. То есть у кнопки только два положения "1" или "0".
Когда я эту кнопку выбираю положительный параметр (т.е.  "1") , то я получаю действительно правильный результат. Однако, когда выбираю "0", то результат я получаю и с параметром "1" и с параметром "0". Я даже принудительно в коде выставил не "OR", а только "AND". Почему же результат при запросе "0" выдаёт, как будто я задал "OR" (либо то либо то), хотя стоит именно "AND" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE название like %$название% OR название_набора like %название_набора% OR артикул="$артикул" AND фабрика="$фабрика"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL](http://mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html)